# How can I reduce the size of the app built by expo/react-native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have developed a simple app(with 3 navigation tabs, some components, no images, using native-base) react-native app using expo-cli.

then I build the app using turtle on online and then app size is 44.6MB.

[image: this is app downloading image]

I think my app size 10MB at maximum. but it is 44.6MB.
I check the build progress and there are so many unwanted modules added.

[image: this is the expo gradle]

I want to make my app as small as possible while using 'expo'.

Comment: Did you try with expo sdk 35 in your project? The 34 have this issue.

Comment: May be try building .aab file instead of .apk. It should be small. For more details https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.9/signed-apk-android#publishing-to-other-stores

Comment: @Oleg. I have just tested with SDK 35 with expo-cli 3.1.1. but app size is 44.5MB.

Comment: https://forums.expo.io/t/build-32bit-only-sdk-35/27998

Comment: Also look at https://forums.expo.io/t/apk-file-size-after-upgrading-is-huge/28034

Comment: This is one of the main issues with Expo as it adds a lot of modules it makes it easy to develop with but at the cost of a large app size, the only way to get the app to be smaller would be to write it using `react native init` and add only the dependencies/modules that you require.

Comment: @andrew, you mean I will rebuild the project using react-native-cli. yeah?

Comment: TBH not exactly a fun thing to do as you would lose all the benefits of Expo, but if apk/aab size is paramount to you then it might be the only way to get a smaller app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Andrew's suggestion is right.
I have reduced the APK size using react-native-cli.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can build app bundle with expo build:android -t app-bundle and then generate apk for specific platforms with https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool